# mysql select all other data using IF NOT IN keyword or alternative

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sql statement which selects data based on using the IN keyword in a where clause but I want to be able to also select data that isn't IN the select argument that is being passed in. I will have a list in the form IN(1,2,6,4) which is being passed in the IN clause. But I want to be able to select all other data that doesn't match what is in the IN clause. Here is a link to my [sample sql](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02a983/6)

```
WHERE pf.filter_value_id IN(1)
```

But I also want to be able to select data that is being passed in using the IN clause.

```
WHERE pf.filter_value_id IS NOT IN(1) // this doesn't work
```

slq which doesn't work:

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.title, fv.filter_value 
  FROM products p    
  INNER JOIN product_filters pf on pf.product_id = p.product_id
  LEFT JOIN filters f on f.filter_id = pf.filter_id
  RIGHT JOIN filter_values fv on fv.filter_value_id = pf.filter_value_id
WHERE pf.filter_value_id IS NOT IN(1)
```

Comment: `NOT IN`, not `IS NOT IN`. `IS` is only used with `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IS NOT IN` is not valid MySQL.  You should be sure to check for query syntax errors.  Instead you just want to check for the [negation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/logical-operators.html#operator_not) of the `IN` clause.  Just `NOT IN` is what you need.